# Rails 5 - how to establish routes for namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces, nested, associations

I am trying to learn how to use namespaced models in my Rails 5 app so as to better organise my content.

I have an address model. It is polymorphic. Each of Settings and Organisation have many addresses. Settings is a model which is namespaced under user.

The associations are

User

```
has_one :setting, dependent: :destroy
```

Setting

```
belongs_to :user

  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable#, class_name: Address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Organisation

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable#, class_name: Address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Address

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true
```

Routes - organisation

```
resources :organisations do
    namespace :contacts do
      resources :addresses
      resources :phones 
    end
  end
```

Routes - setting

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
    scope module: :users do
      resources :identities
      resources :settings do 
        namespace :contacts do
          resources :addresses
          resources :phones 
        end
      end 
    end
  end
```

Organisation form

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= render 'contacts/addresses/address_fields', f: f %>

    <% end %> 
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add another address', f, :addresses, partial: 'contacts/addresses/address_fields' %>
```

user / setting form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @setting] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>
                <%= render 'contacts/addresses/address_fields', f: f %>
            <% end %>       
            <%= link_to_add_association 'Manage address', f, :addresses, partial: 'contacts/addresses/address_fields' %>    

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Everything about my address functionality works fine for Organisation, but I have a problem in getting it to work for my settings.

The problem I have when I try to use the user/setting form to add an address is that I get an error that says:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /contacts/addresses/1/edit
uninitialized constant Users::Contacts
```

There isn't a direct association between user and contacts. Contacts is the name of the namespaced folder I use to store my address views and controller.

Can anyone see what I need to do in order to be able to access the address form functionality from my user settings form?

When I rake routes for setting, I can see the path format to get settings address, but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
rake routes | grep setting
           setting_contacts_addresses GET      /settings/:setting_id/contacts/addresses(.:format)                      users/contacts/addresses#index
                                      POST     /settings/:setting_id/contacts/addresses(.:format)                      users/contacts/addresses#create
         new_setting_contacts_address GET      /settings/:setting_id/contacts/addresses/new(.:format)                  users/contacts/addresses#new
```

**SETTINGS CONTROLLER**

```
class Users::SettingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_setting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @settings = Setting.all
    authorize @settings

  end

  def show
    # authorize @setting

    @addresses = @setting.addresses.all

    @phones = @setting.phones

  end


  def new
    @setting = Setting.new
    @setting.addresses_build 
    @setting.phones_build
    authorize @setting

  end

  def edit
     @setting.addresses_build unless @setting.addresses
     @setting.phones_build unless @setting.phones

  end

  def create
    @setting = Setting.new(setting_params)
    authorize @setting

    respond_to do |format|
      if @setting.save
        format.html { redirect_to @setting }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @setting }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
   respond_to do |format|
      if @setting.update(setting_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @setting }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @setting }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @setting.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to settings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_setting
      @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
      authorize @setting
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def setting_params
      params.require(:setting).permit( :newsletter,
        addresses_attributes: [:id, :description, :unit, :building, :street_number, :street, :city, :region, :zip, :country, :time_zone, :latitude, :longitude, :_destroy],
        phones_attributes: [:phone_number,  :country, :phone_type],

       )
    end

end
```

**ORGANISATIONS CONTROLLER**

```
class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_organisation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @organisations = Organisation.all
    authorize @organisations
  end

  def show
    @addresses = @organisation.addresses.all

    # @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@addresses) do |address, marker|
    #     marker.lat address.latitude
    #     marker.lng address.longitude
    #     marker.infowindow address.full_address
    # end
    @bips = @organisation.bips
    @proposals = @organisation.proposals#.in_state(:publish_openly)    
  end

  def new
    @organisation = Organisation.new
    @organisation.addresses#_build
  end

  def edit
    @organisation.addresses_build unless @organisation.addresses
  end

  def create
    @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @organisation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @organisation, notice: 'Organisation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @organisation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @organisation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @organisation.update(organisation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @organisation, notice: 'Organisation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @organisation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @organisation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @organisation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to organisations_url, notice: 'Organisation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end




private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_organisation
      @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def organisation_params
      params.fetch(:organisation, {}).permit(:title, :comment,
        addresses_attributes:   [:id, :description, :unit, :building, :street_number, :street, :city, :region, :zip, :country, :time_zone, :latitude, :longitude, :_destroy],
        phones_attributes:      [:id, :phone_number,  :country, :phone_type, :_destroy]
        )
    end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish. These codes below allow you to create a new setting for an user. You can add more addresses to that setting. If you want to edit an address'name, you have to go to the edit page of the setting that address belongs to.

routes.rb

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
  scope module: :users do
    resources :settings
  end
end
```

users/settings_controller.rb

```
class Users::SettingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :prepare_user, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :prepare_setting, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def new
    @setting = Setting.new
  end

  def create
    @setting = @user.build_setting(setting_params)
    if @setting.save
      redirect_to @setting
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @setting.update(setting_params)
      redirect_to @setting
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def prepare_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def prepare_setting
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
  end

  def setting_params
    params.require(:setting).permit(:name, addresses_attributes: [:name, :id])
  end
end
```

users/settings/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Setting</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

users/settings/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @setting] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <div>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= render 'contacts/addresses/address_fields', f: f %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add another address', f, :addresses, partial: 'contacts/addresses/address_fields' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

contacts/addresses/address_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.input :name, label: 'Address name' %>
<%= f.input :id, as: :hidden %>
```

Comment: What are you thinking should go inside the []? Does that mean that I also need to specify certain actions for the settings declaration made inside the scope?

Comment: An empty [] would be ok. All the routes for settings is defined in the first `resoures :settings` inside `scope module: :users`. The second `resources :settings` is only to define nested resoures for `addresses` and `phone`, which is not under the namespace `users`

Comment: I tried it, but I still get the same error: uninitialized constant Users::Contacts

Comment: Now i get this error: undefined local variable or method `edit_contacts_address_path' for

Comment: Now the error says: Missing partial contacts/addresses/_form, application/_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:

Comment: I think `shallow: true` makes the form error. Can you try adding `shallow: true` to the organisations routes and check if it works or not?

Comment: removing shallow: true gives the same error. I don't have shallow true in organisations. Organisations works fine as it is

Comment: I mean you try adding `shallow: true` to organisations and check if it works after add

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but everything worked fine, even with your original routes.rb file. Just a notice that `<%= simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>` in user / setting form should be `<%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>`

Comment: which controller? the address controller?

Comment: you have an addresses_controller to edit address directly?

Comment: I don't understand that question. My organisation controller has a line for new/edit address. My settings controller has the same lines.

Comment: yep, then could you post the organisations_controller and settings_controller code?

Comment: ok, is your new setting path something like `/users/1/settings/new`

Comment: this is the `show` path, I mean the `new` path, is the `new path` something like `/users/1/settings/new`?

Comment: did you try to access the path `/contacts/addresses/1/edit` by enter it in the browser address?

Comment: new_setting_contacts_address_path GET /settings/:setting_id/contacts/addresses/new(.:format) 
users/contacts/addresses#new

Comment: I dont get it. If you wanted to create address by using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `simple_fields_for`, then why did you need to access `/settings/:setting_id/‌​contacts/addresses/n‌​ew`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. My routes are nested as I've set out above. I understand that to be the reason why the path is at it is. My address fields are nested inside my user/setting form. I'm trying to figure out how to use that form to handle the address fields.

Comment: It seems to work fine in my organisation use case. It doesnt work at all in my setting case. The difference is setting is nested inside user where organisation is top level

Comment: Im sure that's not right. I don't need hidden fields when I use nested forms.

Comment: My objective is for users to access their address details (all CRUD actions) from their settings page.

Comment: Also. I need to have routes for address in my routes.rb. At the moment, those routes are nested inside each of organisation (where everything works fine) and setting. If I make the change you suggest, then address routes will only be nested inside organisation. That can't be right

Comment: Thanks though for trying to help me.

Comment: your nested form work fine, you can add more addresses to a setting and save it ok. and you want to allow an user when go to his setting page, he can click on the link to edit their addresss, which will lead to an address form, right?

Comment: My nested form works fine inside organisation. I'm trying to get it to work inside settings - it doesnt work at the moment. That's the problem Im trying to solve.

Comment: how do you add, remove and edit an address of an organisation? do you go to the edit organisation page?

Comment: Yes - those actions are covered by my organisation controller

Comment: ok, then why do you need the line `namespace :contacts do
      resources :addresses
      resources :phones 
    end`. you never have to edit an address directly without edit organisation

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I would only ever edit an address through an organisation or a setting

Comment: remove the block `namespace :contacts do resources :addresses resources :phones end` inside `resources :organisations do`. you just need `resources :organisations` and it will work

Comment: Everything inside organisations works just fine the way it is. I'm trying to get it working in setting. It does not work in setting at the moment

Comment: maybe the error comes from your url. you used `shallow: true`, so when you create a new setting, the url must be `users/:user_id/settings/new`, then you have to declare @user variable in your `settings_controller#new` order to use it in `<%= simple_form_for [@user, @setting] do |f| %>`. and when you edit an setting, the url must be `settings/:id/edit`, then the form will be `<%= simple_form_for @setting do |f| %>`

Comment: No. My users/setting/form has: <%= render 'form', setting: @setting %>

Comment: then in `<%= simple_form_for [@user, @setting] do |f| %>`, where does the `@user` come from?